# rails activeadmin gem place active_admin_comments in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin in my application, my reqirement is to display the active_admin_comments in edit page.

I can able to display in index and show pages by placing active_admin_comments in those like

```
 show do
   #Some code
   active_admin_comments
 end
```

but i am not able to do

```
 edit do
   #Some code
   active_admin_comments
 end
```

Is there any way i can active_admin_comments in my edit page or custom page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this

```
ActiveAdmin::Comment
```

in my edit form and it worked.